# Are fairy rings of mushrooms mentioned anywhere in The Dresden Files?

Tags: the-dresden-files

Are Fairy Rings of Mushrooms mentioned anywhere?

[TVTropes on Geometric Magic](https://tvtropes.org/Main/GeometricMagic) says of *The Dresden Files*:

> [Fairies] can use [magic circles] as well, usually constructed from the famous "fairy ring" of mushrooms.
> ...

I don't remember seeing any mention of "fairy ring" in the books... And Google isn't finding anything either.

Are mushroom circles used without calling them fairy rings? Or is my memory accurate and they really don't appear?

Comment: "Fairy ring" is just the (or a) name for a well-defined ring of identical mushrooms.  They were noticed and considered mysterious an inexplicable, although we now know that mushrooms tend to grow that way because they appear around the periphery of an expanding underground fungal colony.

Comment: Toots and his pals used fairy rings of mushrooms _all the time_, and considered them quite magical! You've never had a _mushroom pizza_?

Comment: Nothing in the kindle collection of books 1-6, and I'd expect this to show up early or not at all. Mushrooms are only mentioned as edibiles (or non-edibles). No "fairy", "faery", or "faerie" rings.

Comment: The only place I'd expect them to pop up would be in "Summer Knight" - where some action is in NeverNever, and in Summer. But no mention about that. Mages tend to either make special rings for their labs, makeshift one from a stick or just imagine it, when and if needed. No one will go out look for shrooms in a circle, which will not work anyway, if they need one, as this need tend to be on the urgent side when manifesting.

Comment: A quick search of the first 16 books has zero results for "mushroom" (other than relating to mushroom clouds or edible mushrooms), and zero results for "fairy ring"/"fairy rings"/"faerie ring"/"faerie rings"

Comment: In Guns Of Avalon by R. Zelyazny there is a "Fairy Ring" or "Fairy Circle", "I am told it began as a tiny ring of toadstools"

Answer (score 10):

In *Summer Knight*, chapter 27:

> I squinted at my surroundings next and found a ring of toadstools grown up around me. They weren't huge, tentacular, horribly fanged toadstools or anything, but it put a little chill in me all the same. I lifted my hand and reached out for them tentatively, extending my wizard's senses along with the gesture. I hit a wall. I couldn't think of another way to describe it. Where the ring began, my ability to reach, move, and perceive with my supernatural senses simply ended.
>
> Trapped. Double huzzah.

This was naturally, a prison for Harry made by one of the fae after having been duped into fetching the Unraveling for the big bad fae of the book.

Answer (score 5):

From the short story '[Curses](https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Curses)'

> She stopped beside a ring of large brown mushrooms that grew up out of the floor. I extended my otherworldly senses toward the ring and could feel the quiver of energies moving through the air around the circle like a silent hum of high-tension electrical lines. The substance of mortal reality was thin here, easily torn. The ring of mushrooms was a doorway, a portal leading to the Nevernever, the spirit world.
> I gave Jill a little bow and gestured with one hand. “After you, lady.”
>
> Then she took a step forward, **drawing me into the ring of mushrooms,** and the basement blurred and went away, as if the shadow of an ancient mountain had fallen over us.
> Then the shadow lifted, and we were elsewhere.

Not specifically called a Fairy Ring either.